# sql - group by timestamp/month

Tags: sql

Two of my table ("Faults") columns represents the start ("01:10:2011 12:45:59") and the end (as start's format) of a fault event. My query takes the avg duration (end-start) of each event.

I want to find the average duration of the events grouping by the month  keeping in mind that the timestamp is appeared in the form mentioned above. So, if my table events are:

```
A|SERVICE|        END        |      START
1|ADSL   |1/11/2011 10:00:00 |4/11/2011 10:00:00
2|ADSL   |6/11/2011 12:00:00 |6/11/2011 24:00:00
3|ADSL   |5/12/2011 10:00:00 |6/12/2011 10:00:00
4|ADSL   |7/12/2011 12:00:00 |8/12/2011 24:00:00
```

the grouping result (in days) will be for 11th month the average duration of line 1,2 `([3days+0.5day]/2= 1.75d)` and for the 12th month the average duration of 3,4 that is 1.25 days

```
NOVEMBER|1.75
DECEMBER|1.25
```

Comment: Which SQL-DB do you use?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that your 'timestamps' aren't actual `timestamp` types, but a formatted string?  If so, invest in the time it will take you to convert the database to using the actual type - on-the-fly conversions may eat a fair bit of time (besides the fact that you're not protected from invalid data...).  And different DBs handle timestamps differently - DB2 will only be able to give you an approxiamation, for example (unless you do some ridiculously heavy math).

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to get a month value to group on:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, MIN(Start)) AS [Month], DATEPART(YEAR, Start) As [Year], CONVERT(FLOAT, AVG(DATEDIFF(hour, Start,[End]))) / 24 AS [Days]
    FROM Faults 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(Month, Start), DATEPART(Year, Start)
```

Including the year in GROUP BY is crucial if your data spans multiple years :-)

Of course, if a fault spans a month change, you will need to decide what to do (is the whole fault attributed to the end or the start month, or should it be split ?)